# Sentence ranking algorithms based on importance to the document

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, graph-algorithm

Given any document, what are some algorithms to rank each sentence in it based on it's importance to the document? An important sentence would be one whose removal drastically changes the meaning conveyed by the document, and an unimportant sentence's removal won't affect the document much (or at all)

The algorithm should work independent of domain - it could be a news article, a journal publication, a movie review etc.

If there is no concrete algorithm for something like this, what are some key concepts that one should learn in order to be able to come up with such an algorithm? Where should one begin in approaching this problem?

So far, I've read these two research papers:

[Graph Based ranking](http://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc30957/m2/1/high_res_d/Mihalcea-2004-Graph-Based_Ranking_Algorithms_for_Sentence.pdf)

[Word clusters based ranking](http://eprints.pascal-network.org/archive/00001070/01/1031.pdf)

But I wish to start at the root of the problem, and possibly try to find a new solution to the problem. Hence , I would like to explore more algorithms and understand the basic concepts to get a better understanding of how to approach it.

Comment: What research have you done so far, and what have you found?

Comment: Good.  Look at the bibliographies of those papers and work backwards through the bibliographies of the cited works.  That should lead you to basic concepts.  And anyway, until you've done a thorough literature review, you cannot know whether your proposed solution is new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the bibliographies of the papers you've found and work backwards through the bibliographies of the cited works. That should lead you to basic concepts. And anyway, until you've done a thorough literature review, you cannot know whether your proposed solution is new.  (I posted this as a comment earlier; on reflection, I believe it is a responsive answer to the question.)

Edited to add: You find newer works by checking CiteSeer (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu), Google Scholar, Science Citations Index, etc. to see who has cited the papers you already know about.  Then you follow *their* bibliographies, etc. until you are pretty certain you've covered the work on your topic.  There's a set of tips on conducting a literature review here: http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/specific-types-of-writing/literature-review

You might also want to post a revised version of this question on https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The well-known algorithm for this purpose is the [LexRank](http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cmu.edu%2Fafs%2Fcs%2Fproject%2Fjair%2Fpub%2Fvolume22%2Ferkan04a-html%2Ferkan04a.html&ei=n1MHVNSIM8Kw7Aakz4FY&usg=AFQjCNHDCgWWXl83W7qvBe5FCTRvNGyR6g&sig2=eeDaiXsJUX4vbvllJ2v0xQ&bvm=bv.74115972,d.ZGU). Although it's a bit old, yet it's been heavily cited till date and considered as a strong baseline.